# AngularJS: How to show preload or loading until page is loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image-gallery

I've an image gallery site where I'm getting all images and image related data from the database as json format in my controller and then by using ng-repeat I'm binding them with the html. Now, data are loaded early but images are loaded late, so images are scattered. How to solve this. I don't want to use setTimeOut.

The sample code is as below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="cps">
<body ng-controller="CPSController">
<div>
<li ng-repeat="image in images" class="shown">
                <a id="{{image.imageid}}" ng-click="openimage(image.imageid)">
                    <img idx="id-thumb-{{$index}}" ng-src="/imagedisplay/{{image.imageid}}" alt="" style="">
                    <div class="meta_info">
                        <h3>{{image.imagename}}.</h3>
                        <div class="callto">
                            <div class="actions">
                                <span><img src="img/artist.svg" alt="">{{image.ownername}}</span>
                                <span><img src="img/likes.svg" alt="">{{image.likes}}</span>
                                <span><img src="img/views_small.svg" alt="">{{image.views}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="category">
                                Art Category
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    var cps = angular.module('cps', []);
    cps.controller('CPSController', function($scope, $http, $compile){
        $scope.products = [];
        $http.get("/alldata/").success(function(data){
             if(data != "null")
             {
               for(i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                 $scope.products.push(data[i]);
                }
                $scope.sendOrder('views', 'likes', 'timestamp', 2);
              }else{
                //$('#noImages').show();
              }

           /*setTimeout(function(){
                $("[idx^='id-thumb']").show();
            });*/
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 18):

### `# UPDATE [August 2017]`

Same answer as below except we could work with the `load` event on `window` instead of `DOMContentLoaded` on `document`.  This will ensure that all assets (such as images) in the `window` are *loaded*.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    ...
})
```

---

We don't have to force Angular where `vanilla javascript` can suffice.  This is how it worked for my `AngularJS` project

**Added this to the body tag.  It will be removed with a script tag once HTML Content Loads**

```
<div id="page-loading">
    <img style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" src="styles/img/page-loading.gif">
</div>
```

**`script` tag right under the image.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        /*VANILLA JAVASCRIPT*/
        var element = document.getElementById("page-loading");
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        /* OR WITH jQuery*/
        $('#page-loading')
            .fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```

`DOMContentLoaded` *event* will ensure that the the `callback` is executed when all the `images,fonts,js and other assets` have been loaded.

Good Luck.

Comment: Fantastic solution! Even when we use ng-cloak with Angular, this is still needed for the first load when angular takes time to bootstrap the application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but what I usually do is that I have a `$scope.loaded` variable which has the state of the page. If the page is loaded, the div you want to show is shown... If it's loading, the div with the loader is shown. Have a look at this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/S6Srgz8XveLEHcv3i6ST) to get what I'm trying to say.

I'm pasting the Plunkr code here as well.

**Javascript**

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loaded = true;
    $scope.text = 'Nothing loaded yet.';

    $scope.loadSomething = function () {
      $scope.loaded = false;

      $timeout(function() {
        // Simulates loading
        $scope.text = 'Hello World';
        $scope.loaded = true;
      }, 2000);
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loadSomething()">Load Something</button>
<br/>
<div ng-hide="loaded">
  Loading...
</div>
<div ng-show="loaded">
  <p>{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```

Do let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
angular.element($window).bind('load', function() {
 $scope.yourLoaderDiv=true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While @chotesah answer is just right I can suggest you go another way and use preloaders for each image (something like Facebook on page load).

Try this [module](http://revillweb.github.io/angular-preload-image/).
You'll need to change few lines:

```
// Add module dependency   
angular.module('app', ['angular-preload-image']);
…
<img preload-image idx="id-thumb-{{$index}}" ng-src="/imagedisplay/{{image.imageid}}" default-image="[URL]" fallback-image="[URL]" />
```

After that look for nifty image preloaders at [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/25/freebie-flat-style-squared-preloaders/).

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with same issue. Here is what working on my side where i am showing multiple loading image for each different section based on promise. For this purpose i have created a directive.

My html looks something like below.

```
<mi-loading promise="Loading"></mi-loading>
```

Angularjs directive.

```
(function () {

    var module = angular.module('mi-loading', []);

    module.directive('miLoading', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                promise: '='
            },

            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                $scope.IsLoading = true;

                $scope.$watch('promise', function (prom) {
                    if (!prom) {
                        $scope.IsLoading = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    prom.success(function () { $scope.IsLoading = false; });
                });
            },
            template: '<div ng-show="IsLoading" class="spinner" style="height:300px"></div>'
        };
    });

})();
```

and finally the usage,

```
 var getData = function ()
           {
               var Promise = myservice.getMyData($scope);

               $scope.Loading = Promise;
           };
```

CSS

```
.spinner {
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}

    .spinner:before {
        content: 'Loading…';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        margin-top: -13px;
        margin-left: -13px;
    }

    .spinner:not(:required):before {
        content: '';
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid #ccc;
        /*border-top-color: #03ade0;*/
        border-top-color: #4187b5;
        animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it, i am loading all my scripts at the end of the body.
Before my app-wrapper-div i place a postion fixed "loading"-div. It is shown immediately before other scripts are loaded.

At the end of the body, after my scripts are included, i place an angular directive, that fadeOut and remove the loading-div.

The code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <!-- the only file loaded in the head -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/.../appLoadingScreen.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingScreen">
      <div id="appLoadingScreenCenterWrap">
        <h1 id="appLoadingScreenHeader">APP TITLE</h1>
        <p id="appLoadingScreenMsg">App is loading!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="appWrapper" ng-controller="appCtrl"> 
    ... 
    </div>
    <!-- All stylesheet includes -->
    ...
    <!-- All script includes -->
    ...
    <script src="/.../hideLoadingScreen.js"></script>
    <hide-loading-screen></hide-loading-screen>
</body>
</html>
```

And the hideLoadingScreen directive:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('appModule');
  app.directive('hideLoadingScreen', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          $("#appLoadingScreen").fadeOut(600, function(){$(this).remove();});
        }, 400);
      }
    };
  });
})();
```